# How to use javascript example with external js? highlighting a div after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I've been struggling with Javascript, of which I'm very unfamiliar.

I'd like to highlight the div after scrolling.  I keep finding references to [this highlight example](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/), but anything I try doesn't do anything.

I think the problem is the example is showing how to do it in a simple html file with everything self-contained.  I'm working within a PHP ecommerce platform (prestashop) and have to put the JS and CSS in their respective places.  I'm not understanding how to call what's in that example correctly.  Since I don't get any errors, I don't know how to troubleshoot.  No errors, it just doesn't do anything.

In my HTML I have

```
<div>
  <a onclick="test('myID')">test highlight</a>
  <div id="myID">Here's the div</div>
</div>
```

In the JS I have

```
function test(myId){
  $( document ).click(function() {
    $( myId ).toggle( "highlight" );
  });
}
```

Comment: to access an element with jQuery by Id, you need to use the $("#id"). In your case, you are using $("id"). If I'm not mistaken, you can fix it by changing your $(myId).toggle("highlight"); to $("#" + myId).toggle(...);

Comment: OK, that did something, but not at ALL what I was expecting!  The example from the linked tutorial shows a flash of color, which is what I'm looking for.  After making your adjustment, the DIV disappears and then reappears (with a scrolling affect).  it is eye-catching, certainly, but weird.  And unusuable, really, because the end result is a hidden div!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I fixed your problem buddy ;-)

This is the html

---

```
<div>
    <a>test highlight</a>
    <div id="myID">Here's the div</div>
</div>
```

the jQuery code

```
function test(myId) {
    $("#" + myId).toggle("highlight");
}

$("a").click(function() {
   test("myID"); 
});
```

---

What I did is remove your onclick from the anchor element and binded the click event with jQuery instead. And that did the trick ;-)

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/6c6pr1xd/2/) if you want to see it in action.

**EDIT**

The reason my highlighting wasn't functioning as you wished for, was because I was using an older version of the UI library. And the update also contains a way to use classes to bind click events. The fiddle above will show you.

Comment: I will try it in a sec, but does that mean I have to build a JS function for each and every link I want to do this for?  My hope (which I didn't explain) is that I can have a single JS entry and whenever I want to highlight in this way, I make a reference to it in the call.   But also I don't want the function acting on EVERY "a".

Comment: I tried the fiddle example and the highlight still doesn't work as the example indicates.  In yours, the highlighting stays permanently.  According to the "highlight" jquery ui example, it is supposed to fade quicly.

Comment: you could work with the class of an element. Just give a certain class to every "a" or every element you want to use and bind the "click" event to every element with that function. I'll update the fiddle to show you an example. Just give me a sec.

Comment: check the fiddle once again. I changed it to the way you want ;-)

Comment: I guess Im not being clear, because no that's not what I want.  I want to click an element (a specific <a>) and have another element (the specific <div>) flash color to draw attention to it.  Your fiddle has me clicking one of two elements clickable that result in the div highlighting briefly (what I want) and then disappearing entirely until I click it again (not what I want).  What's with the disappearing act?

Comment: OK, I see the confusion.  The jquery highlight example page does the same thing.  I didn't realize it because they have no text.  Why does everyone link to that example as a method of "highlighting".  That  doesn't highlight at all, really... making something disappear is NOT highlighting!  Sorry, this is off topic now I guess.  I need to draw attention to a section.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you what it more link the Highlight example you linked

you could do it like this:

**EDIT**

Look at this, it will maybe help you:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c6pr1xd/8/)

This is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Click to toggle</p>
    <p>highlight</p>
    <p>on these</p>
    <p>paragraphs</p>
</div>
```

This is the Java script:

```
$('p').toggle(

function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
},

function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white')

});
```

But it is highly dependent on which version of jQuery you end up using.
This example uses 1.8.3

Comment: But don't <script> go into html?  Exactly what I'm trying to not do?

Comment: And again in fiddle, it just highlights and never fades.  And it is still dependent on my hardcoding every ID into the script.  Why's this so hard?  It seems like it should be dead simple.